# Dynamic data updating

Tags: php, database, dynamic, refresh

I'm making an app which accesses a database and updates the data every view seconds over a PHP script, the problem is that it currently always updates all data, I would like to know how to program something that dynamically updates data and decides what data to update and what not, so it basically keeps track of change somehow. So how would I best go along doing something like this ?

I think that there should be some where that this question has already be asked but I couldn't find it so maybe someone can show me a website where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you will need to user either XHR requests, web sockets, or HTTP/2 to solve this problem. Since HTTP/2 is not universally supported on the browser side, it may not work for you. Here is the outline of the solution:

1. Every few seconds, javascript you provide in the browser will need to poll the server for updates using an XHR request. You can use the returned data to update the screen with Javascript. If you only want to do some simple updates, like updating some numbers, you might use raw Javascript or jQuery. If your polling will result in complex screen updates or you want to move a lot of functionality into the client, you probably want to redo your client using one of the JavaScript frameworks like React or Angular.
2. Use web sockets (or HTTP/2) to create a persistent connection to the server, and have the server send updates to the clients as the data changes. This probably will require some code in the application to broadcast or multicast the updates. The client code would be similar to case 1, except that the client would not poll for updates.

The polling solution is easier to implement, and would be a good choice as long as you don't have too many clients sending polls at too high a rate - you can overwhelm the servers this way.